# Windows Backup failed as another backup or recovery is in progress

Tags: backup, sql-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

i have set up backup schedule on our server. SQL Server 2008 to 01:00am on windows server 2008 R2 to 4:00am. Sql backup runs well, but system backup ends sometimes with error.

[image: windows backup error]

The error is : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd364768%28WS.10%29.aspx

I mean, that is caused by SQL Server, because it unexpectedly runs backup.

this is from sql server log (it runs for every database):

> Date      4.2.2010 4:00:21 Log        SQL Server
>   (Current - 29.1.2010 23:25:00)
>
> Source        spid72
>
> Message I/O is frozen on database
>   master. No user action is required.
>   However, if I/O is not resumed
>   promptly, you could cancel the backup.

and

> Date      4.2.2010 4:00:24 Log        SQL Server
>   (Current - 29.1.2010 23:25:00)
>
> Source        Backup
>
> Message Database backed up. Database:
>   master, creation date(time):
>   2010/01/29(23:25:32), pages dumped:
>   370, first LSN: 859:56:37, last LSN:
>   859:80:1, number of dump devices: 1,
>   device information: (FILE=1,
>   TYPE=VIRTUAL_DEVICE:
>   {'{17B91D5C-9968-4D11-A7F1-1A31523D32F0}25'}).
>   This is an informational message only.
>   No user action is required.

My questions is:

Why runs sql backup with windows backup? 
How can i dissolve this that errors?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

did you exclude SQL servers data file from the backup ? Else Windows backup will try to backup them through VSS

How do you backup SQL server ? SQL dumps ?

Comment: No, i haven't exclude anything. There is configured maintanence plan on SQL server for backup.

Comment: As you are doing SQL backup through Maintenance plan, SQL data files must be excluded from the windows backup

Comment: i have database files on system drive and if i want to exclude folders with sql databases, i cannot use bare metal recovery.  doesn't exist another solution? thanks

Comment: poor way: disable the SQL VSS writer through vssadmin, files will be locked and so skipped. I will do some tests to see how to do that the right way

Comment: i turned off sql vss writer and it didnt help. Backup operation succeded, but it logs still the same error:  The backup operation that started at '‎2010‎-‎02‎-‎10T03:00:14.895304600Z' has failed because another backup or recovery operation is in progress.